# Android Emulator - permission denied when pulling files

Tags: android

I have an Android 10 Emulator (API 29) with some RealmDB data files on it that I am trying to pull but I get a permission denied error, even as adb root.

Before when I was using an Android 9 emulator (API 28) I was able to pull the files onto my desktop as adb root by doing the following from cmd:

```
/C:/Users/Blah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools> adb root

/C:/Users/Blah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools> adb pull /data/data/com.myapp/ somewhere/on/my/desktop
```

and this worked fine.

But now I get this error - `adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/data/data/com.myapp/': Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

Try executing this:

```
adb exec-out run-as com.myapp cp /data/data/com.myapp/databases/ /sdcard
```

Or

```
 adb exec-out run-as com.myapp cp /data/data/com.myapp/files/ /sdcard
```

Then,

```
adb pull /sdcard
```

Your database should be in *sdcard* directory.

**Note**: It seems Android R emulator restricted */sdcard* directory unfortunately. However, It should work for emulators with older Android versions. For instance, I tested through a Nexus 6P emulator and it worked properly.

Comment: Any idea how to manage this for Android R emulators? It's the one I have to use!

Comment: @TobiasReich You also could try adb shell 'su root'. Then, cp /data/data/com.myapp/files/the_database /sdcard. Then, type exit. Finally, adb pull /sdcard/the_database